# What is the difference between these packages cloud.storage and appengine.tools.cloudstorage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Can anyone explain what is the difference between these two packages **com.google.cloud.storage** (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/package-summary.html ) and **com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage** (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/package-summary)

Are there any differences in how they function ? Which package is used in which scenario ?

I am developing a Spring MVC application and want to upload files (>100 MB) directly to Cloud Storage and download them without any errors and without going through App Engine instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage` is the old library, only in use for apps running in [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/cloud-storage). It's the only library that Java 7 supports, so if your app is running on Java 7, it's the way to go. However, [the Java 7 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime) has been deprecated, so, I don't recommend going this way.
- `com.google.cloud.storage` is the most recent, and recommended [Cloud Storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). It should be the one that you use in your app, as it's the most recent, updated and compatible library for GCS.Java 7 **doesn't** support this library. Then again, you shouldn't be using Java 7.

Comment: If I am using Cloud Storage client library and To upload file using html form tag, In action = " " What URL we need to mention ? If I mention my controller means, the Upload will be handled by my server running on App Engine or will it directly goes to cloud Storage ? Can you write a answer explaining the full flow in Java ? Thanks in Advance.